# How to create AMI at runtime using AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-lambda

Scenario - 
Running AWS EC2 with AutoScaling to host web servers. Code is hosted on BitBucket.

Requirements -

1. Integrate BitBucket with CodeDeploy for automated deployments.
2. After every successful deployment, create AMI of the running healthy instance.
3. Create a new Launch Configuration for the new AMI.
4. Update existing AutoScaling group.

Comment: I went through above scenario and the challenging part was that Web Servers were running using IIS since it was a .NET app, which means I had to automated configuration part of .NET as well. If you are also into similar situation, then I have written a post of that. Just click on the link below. It works for all kind of environmennts. [http://www.kblearningacademy.com/using-aws-lambda-function-to-create-ami-at-runtime/](http://www.kblearningacademy.com/using-aws-lambda-function-to-create-ami-at-runtime/)

Comment: You might be interested in: http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/03/ami-creation-with-aminator.html and https://www.packer.io/